# Rails. Is the way to access to params hash from model concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to access to params inside my concern

```
module UrlGenerator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def test
    params[:slug]
  end 
end
```

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to access to params inside my [model] concern

No. This is fundamentally wrong and you must not do it.

Only the controller, nothing else, knows your `params` (i.e., the form/CGI parameters). Maybe, if you are careful, you can allow your views (HTML templates) to know about `params`. The rest of your code (models, DB stuff, etc.) does not need those params. They need their own arguments, and it is the controller's job to provide them by translating the `params` to whatever arguments your other methods take.

Comment: i don't want to sound rude but listen to this guy @Ekkehard and review your MVC concepts because if you really need params in you model logic, you are doing something really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below and call test method from the model with parameters :

```
module UrlGenerator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def test(params)
      #define method
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes but in my model i have no access to params hash

Comment: you can also define concerns with controllers, Kindly explain what you want to achieve ?